# User Event script doesn't fire on record sublist modification

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I created a super basic user event script for Sales Order records, shown below. I enabled every execution context and have not set an Event Type filter.

The script executes as expected for events involving the Sales Order record itself, but it does not fire when a modification is made directly to a line item on the Sales Order record. For example, if inventory is committed or reallocated, these actions do not trigger the script.

Are sublist modifications not candidates for user event scripts?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/record", "N/log"],
    function (record, log) {

        function beforeSubmit(context) {
            log.debug("beforeSubmit:" + context.type);
        }

        function afterSubmit(context) {
            log.debug("afterSubmit:" + context.type);
        }

        function beforeLoad(context) {
            log.debug("beforeLoad:" + context.type);
        }

        return {
            beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Events are *not* triggered by changes to records related to the scripted record (e.g. another Transaction, an Item, a Customer, Inventory, etc). A change in Inventory is not a change to the Sales Order, thus it won't trigger Sales Order User Events.

If you want to monitor inventory movements in real-time, you'll need User Events on the records/transactions which cause the movement.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately for me, there doesn't seem to be an exposed record for inventory allocation/commitment to sales orders. The closest I can get currently seems to be a Reallocate Items user event, but the documentation explicitly calls out that this is only for user-driven allocation & not for NetSuite scheduled/automatic allocation.

Comment: Note for future readers - as of NetSuite 2019.2, at least, I wasn't able to find an inventory record I could hook into. However, I was able to use a scheduled script to parse the results of a saved searched created from Setup -> Company -> Bulk Processing Status List. Commit Orders actions both via schedule and user action leave records here.